# BigInteger в С++ или его аналог?

Tags: c++, biginteger

В последнее время программировать приходится имея дело с большими числами, так, что не хватает размеров типа. Как подключить бибилиотеку BigInteger в С++? Это по идее должно решить проблему. 
Или может есть какой-то аналог? Нужно решить задачу, где на вход подаются числа не превышающие 10^100 . Как вообще найти выход из положения?

Comment: GMP, boost::multiprecision, MAPM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[boost-library](https://www.boost.org/users/download/)

boost::multiprecision::cpp_int (BigInteger)

boost::multiprecision::cpp_float - большие числа с плавающей запятой

Comment: "Boost не имя типа"- Выходит,мало скачать и заинклудить библиотеку?

Comment: @MickeyU, boost - одноименное название свободной библиотеки и основного пространства имен этой библиотеки. В вашем случае достаточно просто заинклудить библиотеку, т.к. необходимые вам классы - это шаблоны, они компилируются по мере необходимости и не нужно линковать проект с дополнительными библиотеками.

Answer (score 5):

Классика жанра это GMP. Но есть и другие варианты.

Как-то мне тоже понадобилась длинная арифметика. Но использовать GMP было нельзя, так как длинная арифметика нужна была для микроконтроллеров без операционной системы и кучи. Пришлось написать свою библиотеку С++ шаблонов для работы с длинными целыми числами. Вот ссылка:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/muntl/?source=frontpage&position=5

Там в архиве есть и описание на русском языке.

UPD1:

> А память под переменные и промежуточные результаты выделялась по месту
>   инициализации шаблона в виде массивов с вычисленным во время
>   компиляции размером?

Да, все массивы хранятся статически в объектах класса и размер переменных определяется пользователем на этапе компиляции. То есть внутри этой библиотеки шаблонов обращений к куче нет. Соответственно, нет затрат времени на размещение объектов в куче.

Comment: А память под переменные и промежуточные результаты выделялась по месту инициализации шаблона в виде массивов с вычисленным во время компиляции размером?