# Как вывести большие(очень большие) числа?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Мне нужно умножать очень большие числа, сделал это через алгоритм Карацубы, но переменные просто не могут их вместить в себя. Как можно преодолеть это ограничение?
Код:

```
long int Karatsuba(int A, int B) { // 2n n
    string Astr = to_string(A);
    string Bstr = to_string(B);

    unsigned long int a, b, c, d, sizeA = Astr.size(), sizeB = Bstr.size();

    if (sizeA == 1 || sizeB == 1) return A * B;

    unsigned long int n = max(sizeA, sizeB);

    a = A / static_cast<long int>(pow(10, n / 2));
    b = A % static_cast<long int>(pow(10, n / 2));
    c = B / static_cast<long int>(pow(10, n / 2));
    d = B % static_cast<long int>(pow(10, n / 2));

    unsigned long int p1 = Karatsuba(a, c);
    unsigned long int p2 = Karatsuba(b, d);
    unsigned long int p3 = Karatsuba(a, d) + Karatsuba(b, c);

    return pow(10, n) * p1 + pow(10, n / 2) * p3 + p2;
}
```

Пример чисел, которые нужно переменожить:
3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592 *
2718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627

Comment: Такие числа не входят в допустимый диапазон. Вам следует использовать библиотеки для работы с большими числами. Смотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/856898/biginteger-%d0%b2-%d0%a1-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3/856912)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классика жанра для работы с длинными числами это GMP. Но есть и другие варианты.

Как-то мне тоже понадобилась длинная арифметика. Но использовать GMP было нельзя, так как длинная арифметика нужна была для микроконтроллеров без операционной системы и кучи. Пришлось написать свою библиотеку С++ шаблонов для работы с длинными целыми числами. Вот ссылка:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/muntl/?source=frontpage&position=5

Там в архиве есть и описание на русском языке.